# Haskell function takes 2 parameters but in the definition none

Tags: function, haskell, parameters, pointfree

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to understand a game created in Haskell (tic tac toe). I know that if a function takes n parameters then you must provide n parameters in the function definition. Example:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> String
f a b = "This function makes no sense"
```

However in this Haskell script there is a function that takes two arguments but in the definition it has none. And of course, it's working but I can't seem to figure out why.

```
import Data.Map qualified as M
type Board = M.Map (Int, Int) Marker
data Marker = X | O | Blank deriving Eq

getMarker :: Board -> (Int, Int) -> Marker
getMarker = flip $ M.findWithDefault Blank
```

Any ideas on what this function does and more importantly, why it's working (you can see that `getMarker` takes 0 parameters at the last line) ?

Comment: "*I know that if a function takes n parameters then you must provide n parameters in the function definition.*" False, you can decide to write *n* parameters in the function definition and generate a function that takes the remaining arguments. That's one of the basic concepts of functional programming.

Comment: What do you mean by the remaining arguments?

Comment: If the expression `flip $ M.findWithDefault Blank` yields a function of the desired type, calling `getMarker` will call _that_ function directly, and `getMarker` doesn't have to touch the arguments to pass them through.

Comment: `f = (+)` defines a 2-argument function, and is equivalent to `f x y = (+) x y`. What is really weird is that, in some cases, there is no clear notion of "number of arguments". Consider `f x = x`. It has one argument. But is also has 5: `f f f f f 1` evaluates to `1`. Function `f` has N parameters for any `N`.

Comment: In reality, *all* functions in Haskell take a single argument; a "two-argument" function really just returns another function. The left associativity of function application allows something like `f x y` (which is explicitly parenthesized as `(f x) y`) *look* like `f` is being applied to two arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The misconception is here:

> ... (you can see that `getMarker` takes 0 parameters at the last line) ...

and the thing that's puzzling you is [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application).

---

```
getMarker :: Board -> (Int, Int) -> Marker
getMarker = flip $ M.findWithDefault Blank
```

What that last line *actually* tells you is that the `getMarker` doesn't *do* anything with its arguments - but they still get passed to the function created by `flip $ M.findWithDefault Blank`.

Or, more accurately, `getMarker` evaluates to a function of the declared type which is *applied to* `getMarker`'s arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You have `getMarker :: Board -> (Int, Int) -> Marker`, so it's called like

```
getMarker board pos
```

Since you have `getMarker = flip $ M.findWithDefault Blank`, this is equivalent to:

```
(flip $ M.findWithDefault Blank) board pos
```

Expanding `$`:

```
(flip (M.findWithDefault Blank)) board pos
```

Function application is left associative, so `(f x) y` is equivalent to `f x y`.

```
flip (M.findWithDefault Blank) board pos
```

`flip f x y` is equivalent to `f y x`, so the expression is equal to:

```
(M.findWithDefault Blank) pos board
```

Again, thanks to left associativity of function application:

```
M.findWithDefault Blank pos board
```

And this is sensible.